# Positioning the cursor with the mouse inside nano

Tags: terminal, mouse

I'm using the nano editor inside MacOS `Terminal` and `iTerm2`. My .nanorc contains the statement

```
set mouse on
```

and I can select text with the mouse.

However, I can not move the text insertion cursor with a mouse. Is this a principal of the mouse support in nano, or is this something which can be configured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> + click in nano to move text cursor to the desired position.

Comment: This works in regular Terminal too.